# Replacing a word in a config file is inserting the new word in other configs that are partly the same.

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

So I have a script that I was building to replace words in a very large config file that I am rebuilding and renaming. So I will give an example of what it is that is going on. Lets say in the server line of the load balancer config I have "web01" and want to change it to "web01_svr", it works fine. But on the "add service" line I might have "web01-80-HTTP_sg". The script is inserting itself to make it "web01_svr-80-HTTP_sg". How do I specify in this script to only match exact objects and not partial?

```
with open('massiveconfig.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
```

## Replace the target string

```
while True:
    old = input("What is the old name you would like to replace?: ")
    new = input("What is the new name you would like to replace the old 
    with?: ")
    filedata = filedata.replace(old, new)
    cont = input("Would you like to replace another?: Y/n")


# Write the file out again
    with open('massiveconfig.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: Don't read from and write to the same file at the same time. Instead read the whole file first, close it, do your processing, then write it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to the rescue:

```
import re

filedata = re.sub(r'\b'+ old +r'\b(?![-])', new, filedata)
```

You are not very specific, which special characters might be present in your words. I assume, `_` or `.` are to be expected. In this case, you can adapt the script and use `[-_.]` instead of `[-]`